# android replace emogi with icon

Tags: android

I have an array of emogis:

```
 String rr [] = {":)",":D",":(",":'(",":P",":P","3:)","o.O",";)",":O","-_-",">:O",":*","<3","^_^","8-)","8|","(^^^)",
        ":|]",">:(",":v",":/",":3","☺","(y)",":poop:",":putnam:","<(\")","✌","☀","☁","☔","⚡","✨","⭐","✳", 

        "","","",
        "","","〽","","","","","","","" 
};
```

I need to replace in this String

```
String mm = "Hello wold :D :P try emotions ";
```

All those emotions I have them as icon too in drawable how can i replace all
simple in string to icon and append them to a `textView`?

what i want

this is my string

```
String mm = "Hello wold :D :P try emotions ";
```

there are three emotions on it

and i have array of icon

i want to replace all emotions in the string with those icon i have it

```
      int icon[] = {R.drawable.a,R.drawable.b,R.drawable.c,R.drawable.d,R.drawable.e};
      String rr [] = {":)",":D",":(",":'(",":P",":P","3:)","o.O",";)",":O","-_-",};
```

so find those in string `String rr []` and replace them with `icon[]` array for shown them in textView if this correct way how can i find and replace

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SpannableString` with your `TextView`. This type of strings allows you to have inline images in your `TextView`.

For each emotion icon, you would need to create an `ImageSpan`. This `ImageSpan` can be inserted into the string as an inline image.

```
ImageSpan is = new ImageSpan(context, R.drawable.arrow);
```

So, you should now find all emotion characters and replace them with `ImageSpan`s.

```
SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Your string here");

// Insert an ImageSpan into the string
text.setSpan(is, 5, 5 + 10, 0);
```

And apply it to the `TextVeiw`.

```
textView.setText(text);
```

Comment: i dont get it how can i found _all emotion characters and replace them with ImageSpans._ here its is my problem

Comment: @medo [String.indexOf](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_indexof.htm)?

Comment: i beginner  its an array not only on smile 
`hello :P :P :P :P :P <3` many smiles there i want to check if there are an word of this string in my array smile if there replace it with and icon with same index of my array emogi

Comment: @medo Sorry, I couldn't understand what you say. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38944050/edit) your question and clarify what you say.

Comment: @medo It's a simple job! You should iterate through `rr` array and for each item check whether it exists within the main string, if it does, simply remove it and place a `ImageSpan` there. that's it!

Comment: it's expensive did there are method like php regular express ?

Comment: @medo I don't think so. Nevertheless, yes Java has regular expressions.